# How to Bind CurrentCell in WPF datagrid using MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I'm learning WPF MVVM pattern. I'm stuck in `Binding CurrentCell` of `datagrid`. Basically I need the row index and column index of current cell.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
          SelectionUnit="Cell" 
          CanUserDeleteRows="True" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Results}" 
          CurrentCell="{Binding CellInfo}" 
          Height="282" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Margin="12,88,0,0" 
          Name="dataGrid1" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Width="558" 
          SelectionMode="Single">
```

Here is my ViewModel

```
private User procedureName = new User();

public  DataGridCell   CellInfo
{
    get { return procedureName.CellInfo; }
    //set
    //{
    //    procedureName.CellInfo = value;
    //    OnPropertyChanged("CellInfo");
    //}
}
```

Here is my Model

```
private DataGridCell cellInfo;

public DataGridCell CellInfo
{
    get { return cellInfo; }
    //set
    //{
    //    cellInfo = value;
    //    OnPropertyChanged("CellInfo");
    //}
}
```

And in my ViewModel `CellInfo` is always `null`. I am not able to get the value from the `currentcell` in `datagrid`. Please let me know a way to get`CurrentCell` in the ViewModel.

```
if (CellInfo != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Value is" + CellInfo.Column.DisplayIndex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: CurrentCell="{Binding CellInfo}" - Try setting this thing to binding mode two way.

Comment: why do you need cell info, can't you bind to a selected item of the data grid and extract the properties you need from there?  Also, calling the messagebox from your viewmodel is going to create problems.  Was that just for testing?

Comment: Thanks.I tried with SelectedItem.Even selecteditem is null in my view model.yes messagebox is just for testing.

Comment: @devhedgehog I tried with mode two way also.but i didnt get the CurrentCell in my View model.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After having a quick poke-around I've noticed a very simple solution to your problem.

First of all there's two problems rather then one here. You cannot bind a `CellInfo` of a type   `DataGridCell`, it needs to be `DataGridCellInfo` as xaml cannot convert it on its own.

Secondly in your xaml you will need to add `Mode=OneWayToSource` or `Mode=TwoWay` to your `CellInfo` binding.

Here is a rough example semi-related to your original code

XAML

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True"
          SelectionUnit="Cell"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          Height="250" Width="525" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Results}"
          CurrentCell="{Binding CellInfo, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
```

VM

```
private DataGridCellInfo _cellInfo;
public DataGridCellInfo CellInfo
{
    get { return _cellInfo; }
    set
    {
        _cellInfo = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("CellInfo");
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Column: {0}",
                        _cellInfo.Column.DisplayIndex != null ? _cellInfo.Column.DisplayIndex.ToString() : "Index out of range!"));
    }
}
```

Just a small tip - if you debug your app and look at the Output window it actually tells you if there is any troubles with your bindings.

Hope this helps!

K.

Comment: Thank you very much kosdos.This works well as suggested.I tried same thing before, but while testing i tried in butoon click command.so whenever  i clicked on button CurrentCell lost its focus that was the reason i got always null.Now i got correct value by testing inside set.Also thanks for your tip.

Comment: @kosdos `_cellInfo.Column.DisplayIndex != null ? _cellInfo.Column.DisplayIndex.ToString()` would always be true.BTW,how to get the seleted cell's row index?

Comment: @Chenxiao There are multiple ways of extracting row index, here are a few:

 - `DataGrid` contains a property called `SelectedIndex`, if this works correctly for you (really finicky if used when you are switching rows and such as far as i remember)

Comment: - Non MVVM approaches include: `int rowIndex = dataGrid1.Items.IndexOf(cell.Item);` or
   `var currentRowIndex = my_dataGrid.Items.IndexOf(my_dataGrid.CurrentItem);`
 - In case of MVVM approaches: `SelectedItem`'s index location within the object that is binded to the datagrid should be the same as the item's row unless you are applying custom filtering, visualization or simmilar logic.

These are a few that pop into my head at this moment, hope it helps!