# DataGrid Single Cell row and column from click using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, model-view

I have DataGrid and I am trying to get the cell details (column,row and value) of a selected cell using MVVM and avoid putting in any changes to the code behind.

My data grid looks like this

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyData}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" GridLinesVisibility="None" SelectionUnit="Cell">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn  Header="a" Width="130" Binding="{Binding Path=A}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn  Header="b"   Width="100" Binding="{Binding Path=B}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn  Header="c"   Width="100" Binding="{Binding Path=C}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick"  Command="{Binding DataGridLeftClick}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MyDataGrid, Path=SelectedCells}" />
    </DataGrid.InputBindings>
```

in my ViewModel I have

```
   DataGridLeftClick = new RelayCommand(LeftClick);
   ...

   public ICommand DataGridLeftClick { get; private set; }

   public void LeftClick(object obj)
   {   
       log.Info(obj);
   }
```

The command works but there are two things the value of obj is always null.  If I remove the SelectionUnit of the grid (so i assume it defaults to FullRow) then I get the data of the full rows cells.  How do I get the cell row,index and value of a single the cell that was clicked on?

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered DataGridView.CurrentCell Property and with binding to the VM {Binding CurrentCellVMProperty, Mode=OneWayToSource}.

Also see this answer: [How to Bind CurrentCell in WPF datagrid using MVVM pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080130/how-to-bind-currentcell-in-wpf-datagrid-using-mvvm-pattern)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Spent alot of time searching the web but didn't come across this.  Thanks.